# multer is getting req.file but not req.filename, also the image is not being uploaded to the directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, multer

I am trying to get groupDP in groupDps folder and i am uploading the image using multer and axios but i am only getting req.file and not the actual file, also req.filename is absent
this is my multer code
i have one more function in multer.js that is userDps thats for uploading user dps in another folder
i dont know what the problem is... tried gpt too, no result

```
// Import required modules
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid"); // Used for generating unique filenames
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

// Configure storage options for multer
const Groupstorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Set destination directory for uploaded files
    console.log("fudge")
    cb(null, __dirname+"/images/groupDps");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Generate unique filename using UUID v4 and keep original file extension
    const uniqueFileName = uuidv4();
    cb(null, uniqueFileName + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const userDpStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Set destination directory for uploaded files
    cb(null, __dirname+"./public/images/userDps");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req)
    // Generate unique filename using UUID v4 and keep original file extension
    const uniqueFileName = uuidv4();
    cb(null, uniqueFileName + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});



// Define file filter function to only allow image files
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image/")) {
    // Accept only files with MIME type starting with 'image/'
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    // Reject files with other MIME types
    cb(new Error("Only image files are allowed"));
  }
}

// Configure multer middleware with Groupstorage and file filter
const uploadGroupDPs = multer({ Groupstorage, fileFilter });

const uploadUserDPs = multer({ userDpStorage, fileFilter });

// Export configured multer middleware for file upload handling
module.exports = {uploadGroupDPs, uploadUserDPs};
```

!!JS code of how the form is uploaded

```
newGroup.addEventListener('click', () => {
  overlay.classList.remove('left-[-100%]');
  var template = `<header class="w-full h-1/6 bg-[#202C33] flex items-center justify-start gap-8 text-slate-300 px-5 pt-10 text-xl font-medium">
  <i class="cursor-pointer ri-arrow-left-line"></i>
  <p>New Group</p>
</header>
<div class="h-5/6 w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-start bg-[#111B21]">
  <div id="imagePreview" class="h-[33%] cursor-pointer w-[45%] bg-[url(../images/group.png)] bg-center bg-cover rounded-full mt-7" onclick="selectFile()"></div>
  <form action="/create/groupId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input hidden id="chooseImage" name="groupImage" type="file" onchange="getImage(this)">
  <div class="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-start h-[25%] mt-14 px-8">
    <div class="w-full text-slate-400 flex items-center justify-between text-lg">
      <input id="groupName" type="text" placeholder="Group Name" onclick="groupHover()" class="group bg-transparent outline-none">
      <i class="ri-emoji-sticker-line"></i>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="groupBorder" class="w-full border-t-2 mt-1 border-slate-400"></div>
    <div id="groupConfirm" class="bg-[#00A884] text-3xl font-medium text-slate-200 rounded-full mt-10 items-center justify-center flex h-12 w-12">
      <i class="ri-check-line cursor-pointer"></i>
    </div>
  </div>`
  overlay.innerHTML = template;

  const groupConfirm = document.getElementById('groupConfirm');
  let groupName = document.getElementById('groupName');
  
  groupConfirm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const groupObject = {
      groupName: groupName.value,
      groupCreator: loggedInUser,
    } 

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('groupImage', imageData);
    // console.log(imageData)
    formData.append('groupObject', JSON.stringify(groupObject)); // Convert object to string

    // Send group creation request to the server
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/create/groupId', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        appendChat(response.data._id,response.data.groupProfileImage,
          response.data.groupName,"");
        overlay.classList.add('left-[-100%]');
      })
  const imagePreview = document.getElementById("imagePreview");

  groupName.value = "";
  imagePreview.classList.add("bg-[url(../images/group.png)]");
  imagePreview.style.backgroundImage = ``;
  })
});
```

```
router.post('/create/groupId', uploadGroupDPs.single('groupImage'), contollers.createGroup);

controller.createGroup = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const groupObject = JSON.parse(req.body.groupObject); // Parse group object from request body
    const { groupName, groupCreator } = groupObject; // Destructure group properties
    // Create new group in database
    const newGroup = await groupModel.create({
      groupName: groupName, // Set group name 
      groupProfileImage: "/images/groupDps/" + req.file.filename, // Set group profile image path
      admin: groupCreator, // Set group admin
    });

    newGroup.members.push(groupCreator); // Add group creator as member
    await newGroup.save(); // Save new group to database
    res.send(newGroup); // Send response with created group data
  } catch (error) {
    next(error); // Pass any errors to the error handling middleware
  }
};
```

this is what req.file returns

```
{
  fieldname: 'userImage',
  originalname: '599379.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff fe 00 3b 43 52 45 41 54 4f 52 3a 20 67 64 2d 6a 70 65 67 20 76 31 2e 30 20 28 75 73 69 ... 405029 more bytes>,
  size: 405079
}
```

Comment: Please remember to remove offensive language from your code before posting it.